Inverse of a piecewise non-continuous function
Let
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x-2,  & \text{if $x \leq1$} \\
\frac{1}{x^2-1}, & \text{if $x>1$}
\end{cases}$$
For $x\leq1$
$f'(x)=2>0 \implies f$ is increasing at $(- \infty,1]$ the range of $(- \infty,1]$ is $(-\infty , 0]$ inverse function $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x+2}{2}$ for every $x \in (-\infty,0]$ (*?)
For $>1$
$f'(x)=-\frac{2x}{(x^2-1)^2} <0 \implies f$ is decreasing at $(1,+\infty)$ and the range there is $(0,+\infty)$ the inverse function $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{\sqrt{1+x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ for every $x \in (0,+\infty)$ (**?)
I know that the inverse of a piecewise function can be a piecewise function but in this example $f$ "changes" at $x=1$ but the inverse at $x=0$. Is that correct ? Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Seems okay to me, yes. With a piecewise function $f$ defined separately for $x\leq a$ and $x>a$ if you have an inverse, the closed for of the inverse will be piecewise based on $f(a).$ The two pieces could be $x\leq f(a)$ and $x>f(a)$ or they could be $x<f(a)$ and $x\geq f(a).$

I prefer to use a different argument for $f^{-1},$ which makes it more clear why the piecewise of the inverse will use different pieces. If you write $f^{-1}(y)=\frac{y+2}2$ when $y\leq 0,$ it is less jarring that you have different pieces. The reuse of $x$ gives the feeling they should be more related. Not technically wrong, but it gives a wrong intuition.

The domain and co-domain are reversed in the inverse... So, it is only natural that the branching point occurs at $f(1) = 0$.

@ThomasAndrews thank you, So it is more clear to use different variables for the different pieces ?
